# Write to a new, modified Excel file from an original one

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, excel

I noticed that I've a HUGE bottleneck in this following function of mine. I can't see how to make it faster.

These are the profiling test results(keep in mind that I'm using a PyQt GUI so times can be stretched):

[cProfile Results](http://pastebin.com/LqwMj8h9)

```
def write_workbook_to_file(self, dstfilename):
    self.populaterownumstodelete()
    # actual column in the new file
    col_write = 0
    # actual row in the new file
    row_write = 0
    for row in (rows for rows in range(self.sheet.nrows) if rows not in self.row_nums_to_delete):
        for col in (cols for cols in range(self.sheet.ncols) if cols not in self.col_indexes_to_delete):
            self.wb_sheet.write(row_write, col_write, self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, col))
            col_write += 1
        row_write += 1
        col_write = 0
```

I ran a `cProfile` profiling test and `write_workbook_to_file()` resulted the slowest function in all my application. `parseandgetcellvalue()` isn't a problem at all.

Comment: I don't know Python, but it looks like you're iterating through every cell (row & column) in the sheet. That will definitely be slow. Just for the sheer number of iterations. What are trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I have some columns / rows in the original excel file that does not have to be showed in the new file. These informations are stored in col_indexes_to_delete and in row_nums_to_delete.

Comment: Why not copy everything (all at once via a Range) and then delete what needs to be deleted, instead of only copying the final dataset?

Comment: I should need to "move" the rows / columns then.. I don't think it's a good idea. I've updated my code now (I'm so tired right now ahah)

Comment: I've replaced the newest code block with the original one.  There's no need for multiple of them.

Comment: I thought that maybe it could be useful to see the "differences" between each code modification. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it faster you could move this

```
(cols for cols in range(self.sheet.ncols) if cols not in self.col_indexes_to_delete)
```

out of the loop, and use `enumerate` instead of explicitly incrementing variables.

Revised code:

```
def write_workbook_to_file(self, dstfilename):
    self.populaterownumstodelete()
    rows = [row for row in xrange(self.sheet.nrows) if row not in self.row_nums_to_delete]
    cols = [col for col in xrange(self.sheet.ncols) if col not in self.col_indexes_to_delete]
    for row_write, row in enumerate(rows):
        for col_write, col in enumerate(cols):
            self.wb_sheet.write(row_write, col_write, self.parseandgetcellvalue(row, col))
```

In fact you could even move `enumerate` out of the loop, but I like how the code looks quite clean now.

Comment: Fantastic solution! Thanks for showing me enumerate()! It's just PERFECT used here!